# NSIS Directory Page without changeable Field

Tags: nsis

In the directory page of the NSIS installer I want to show the installation path but without changing it.

[image]

I makes in the Directory.nsh EnableWindow for the fields:

```
    ;Get control handles
    FindWindow $mui.DirectoryPage "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.Text $mui.DirectoryPage 1006
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.DirectoryBox $mui.DirectoryPage 1020
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.Directory $mui.DirectoryPage 1019
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton $mui.DirectoryPage 1001
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.SpaceRequired $mui.DirectoryPage 1023
    GetDlgItem $mui.DirectoryPage.SpaceAvailable $mui.DirectoryPage 1024
    EnableWindow $mui.DirectoryPage.Directory 0
    EnableWindow $mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton 0
```

Now the fields are gray and blocked:

[image]

But that's not what I want:

- the button should disappear
- The directory field should be larger and with normal brightness, i.e. a normal field

How do I do it?

Comment: These UI patterns are best kept as designed, they communicate functionality ("this control cannot be changed") and shouldn't be about (your) personal preference. Changing the colours also has an impact on people that use different themes e.g. for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, this is a bad idea. The user can also set a different `$InstDir` with `/D` on the command line.

You can make the edit field read-only instead of disabling it, this way the user can at least select/copy the text. The control might still be grayed out, it depends on the active Windows visual style/theme.

You can use `MUI_UI` and a custom UI file or resize the control at run-time:

```
InstallDir "$Temp\Whatever"
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LockDirPage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function LockDirPage
EnableWindow $mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton 0
ShowWindow $mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton 0
SendMessage $mui.DirectoryPage.Directory ${EM_SETREADONLY} 1 ""
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(p$mui.DirectoryPage.Directory,@r1)'
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(p$mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton,@r2)'
System::Call *$2(i,i,i.r2)
System::Call *$1(i.r3,i.r4,i,i.r6)
IntOp $3 $2 - $3 ; Width
IntOp $4 $6 - $4 ; Height
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(p$mui.DirectoryPage.Directory,p0,i0,i0,ir3,ir4,i0x16)'
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: How does a custom page help you to get a edit box the user can't edit?

Answer (score 0):

this is my custom page
showing the install path

[image]

Comment: The downside to using a custom page is of course that you lose the disk space check provided by the directory page.

Comment: I could install disk space checking, what for?